# how to merge dataframes with string timestamps of different frequency

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 csv datafiles from different sources that I would like to merge. Both files have a string timestamp for each row, but very different periods - one is every 2 seconds, the other every hour. I can import them to Pandas, and have tried to merge them but have 2 problems.

1) I can convert the timestamp to a pandas datetime64 object using pd.to_datetime, but this creates a new series, losing the data column. Can the conversion be done "in-place"?
my attempt is:
newdf = pd.to_datetime(calc_insol.iloc[:,0]) # calc_insol is the DF

2) assuming I can get both DFs into the correct datetime format, can they be merged given the very large difference in timestamp periods.

An extract of each DF is shown below. The string timestamp is col 0, the "data" is in col 1
calc_insol:

```
0   2017-May-19 2:00:00 0
1   2017-May-19 3:00:00 0
2   2017-May-19 4:00:00 0
3   2017-May-19 5:00:00 0
4   2017-May-19 6:00:00 0
5   2017-May-19 7:00:00 0
6   2017-May-19 8:00:00 497.5
7   2017-May-19 9:00:00 685.2
8   2017-May-19 10:00:00    768.4
9   2017-May-19 11:00:00    806.3
10  2017-May-19 12:00:00    816.6
11  2017-May-19 13:00:00    803.1
12  2017-May-19 14:00:00    760.6
13  2017-May-19 15:00:00    668.7
14  2017-May-19 16:00:00    456.8
15  2017-May-19 17:00:00    0
16  2017-May-19 18:00:00    0
17  2017-May-19 19:00:00    0
18  2017-May-19 20:00:00    0
19  2017-May-19 21:00:00    0
20  2017-May-19 22:00:00    0
21  2017-May-19 23:00:00    0
22  2017-May-20 0
```

meas_insol:

```
2017-May-19 11:59:57    89.8
2017-May-19 11:59:59    80.57
2017-May-19 12:00:01    90.64
2017-May-19 12:00:03    93.15001
2017-May-19 12:00:05    85.6
2017-May-19 12:00:07    78.89
2017-May-19 12:00:09    85.6
2017-May-19 12:00:11    75.53
2017-May-19 12:00:13    93.99
2017-May-19 12:00:15    93.15001
2017-May-19 12:00:17    92.32
2017-May-19 12:00:19    87.28
2017-May-19 12:00:21    77.21
2017-May-19 12:00:23    92.32
2017-May-19 12:00:25    79.73001
2017-May-19 12:00:27    76.37001
2017-May-19 12:00:30    74.69
2017-May-19 12:00:32    88.96
2017-May-19 12:00:34    73.85
2017-May-19 12:00:36    78.89
2017-May-19 12:00:38    76.37001
2017-May-19 12:00:40    77.21
2017-May-19 12:00:42    88.12
2017-May-19 12:00:44    87.28
2017-May-19 12:00:46    88.12
2017-May-19 12:00:48    79.73001
2017-May-19 12:00:50    74.69
2017-May-19 12:00:52    77.21
2017-May-19 12:00:54    83.92
2017-May-19 12:00:56    73.85
2017-May-19 12:00:58    83.92
2017-May-19 12:01:00    83.08001
2017-May-19 12:01:02    74.69
2017-May-19 12:01:04    78.89
2017-May-19 12:01:06    73.85
2017-May-19 12:01:08    86.44
2017-May-19 12:01:10    74.69
2017-May-19 12:01:12    73.01
2017-May-19 12:01:14    68.82
2017-May-19 12:01:16    83.92
```

Ideally the finished DF will have col 0 as the datetime object and col 1 will be data from calc_insol, while col 2 will be data from meas_insol.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If my answer have no desired output, can you add it to question? also there is no match between dates, can you changed it? (3 -5 rows in sample is OK). thank you.

Comment: thanks - I've changed the data selection so they overlap. Also used your suggestion and have now got the timestamps fixed in each file. I can't check the merging right now, but will tomorrow when back in the office.

Comment: Sorry, now  I am a bit confused - do you need first `meas_insol` upsample to `hours` like `calc_insol` and then merge?

Comment: No - the calc_insol column can be sparse, so there will be only 1 hourly timestamp for calc, but 2 sec timestamps for meas. In practice the measurements are made every 2 seconds but the calculations are only hourly.

Comment: Ok, so how they dataframes are joined? Only by datetime from `calc_insol` with hour precision? So output is daframe with all dates which are matched from both df?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Comment: Ok, so my solution works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need create new `datetime` columns and merge with them and last remove `new` column by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) - then original columns are not changed:

```
calc_insol['new'] = pd.to_datetime(calc_insol.iloc[:,0])
meas_insol['new'] = pd.to_datetime(meas_insol.iloc[:,1])
df = pd.merge(calc_insol, meas_insol, on='new')
#if necessary
df = df.drop('new',axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks - this has worked. It would be useful to have all the meas_insol timestamps even if there is no associated calc_incol data as well. Maybe without on='new'?

Comment: Hmmm, I think need `how='left'` or `how='right'`,  ;)

Comment: yes - this worked: df_merged = pd.merge(calc_insol, meas_insol, how = 'left', on='new')     this produced a df with all the data - every hour timestamp (i.e. on the hh:00:00) has both meas and calc, while meas has a value for every timestamp. Thanks!

Comment: Supeer. Nice day!